# How can I make a standalone document loading siunitx work?

Tags: siunitx, standalone

I've got a standalone document that uses `siunitx`:

```
% subdocument.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kilo\newton}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to include this standalone document as a sub-document in a different document, using the `standalone` package. Because I don't want to manually keep track of which packages are needed for the sub-document, I want to use the `subpreambles=true` option of `standalone`:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{subdocument.tex}
\end{document}
```

However, if I do that, I get an error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l__siunitx_option_deactivate_clist
```

I could fix this by loading `siunitx` in `main.tex`, but I hope that there is a different way around this.

---

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{subdocument.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
    \SI{10}{\kilo\newton}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

% This works (loading siunitx only in the main document)
%\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

% This doesn't (loading siunitx in the sub-document), but it would be nice if it did:
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{subdocument.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't a good way to proceed; packages that do some of their jobs `\AtBeginDocument` are likely to fail here. I see `subpreambles=true` for defining macros used in the subdocument, not for loading packages.

Comment: As the documentation of `standalone` explains, the packages loaded in the subpreambles are stored in an auxiliary file and they are eventually loaded using `\AtBeginDocument`. But when `\@begindocumenthook` is executed, `\AtBeginDocument` is redefined to be `\@gobble`, so *no* code those packages want to delay at begin document sees the light.

Comment: as @cgnieder figured out in chat, it works when using pure `\usepackage{standalone}` in combination with `\unexpanded` `siunits`. Therefore, you need to load `siunitx` within the main document

Comment: could `standalone` then use the `etoolbox` `\AtEndPreamble` rather than `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @egreg: Can we cancel the redefinition `\AtBeginDocument` to `\@gobble`?

Comment: @Marienplatz I don't think it's a safe thing to do.

Comment: @egreg: Is it easy to do the cancellation regardless of whether or not it is safe? We can make a new key option to cancel the redefinition and just warn the user that it might be not safe. As it may be impossible to test for each scenario the users apply, just wait for the bug report. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that just adding `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\AtBeginDocument}[1]{}}` before loading the `standalone` package makes the MWE compile correctly. This is definitely not the correct solution since this throws away all the things that the `siunitx` package thinks need to be done in `\AtBeginDocument`. If instead we go with an MWE of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\AtBeginSubDocument}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\AtBeginDocument}[1]{\apptocmd{\AtBeginSubDocument}{#1}{}{}}}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\AtBeginDocument{\meaning\AtBeginSubDocument}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginSubDocument}
\begin{document}
\input{subdocument.tex}
\end{document}
```

The MWE compiles and shows that about 2 pages worth of content is being checked in `\AtBeginDocument`. Much of this looks like checks to see if packages are loaded (i.e., `@ifpackageloaded`) and there may be package combinations that cause problems.