# Is it possible to usepackage inside an input or include file?

Tags: packages, input, include, dependencies

In other words, Can I put the package dependencies of an included file inside the file itself? Or I must use the main file for that?

I am in a situation in which I include different slides in a `main.tex` file.
Different slides use commands using different packages.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepakcage{apackage}
\usepackage{bpackage}
\title{Title}
\author{hola}
\begin{document}
\include{slide1} %slide1.tex needs apackage
\include{slide2} %slide2.tex needs bpackage
\end{document}
```

**Can I write `slide1.tex` and `slide2.tex` in such a way that `main.tex` doesn't need to know the packages needed by its slides?**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Title}
\author{hola}
\begin{document}
\include{slide1} %slide1.tex needs apackage, slide1.tex declares its own needed package
\include{slide2} %slide2.tex needs bpackage, slide2.tex declares its own needed package
\end{document}
```

And (not working code) `slide1.tex` is

```
"\usepackage{apackage}"
\begin{frame}
\commandfromapackage{...}
\end{frame}
```

This is of course a feature very common in languages like C, in which it included file can declare their own dependencies.

Of course it could be that the solution is to write this `main.tex`, but that would be terrible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{slide1_packages}
\input{slide2_packages}
\title{Title}
\author{hola}
\begin{document}
\include{slide1}
\include{slide2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are (the contents of) `apackage` and `bpackage` in conflict with each other? If they're not, why not just load them both? Aside: You've already "discovered" that `\usepackage` is a preamble-only instruction, right?

Comment: @Mico They are not necessarely in conflict. Yes, I know that, I am looking for a workaround to make the writing of documents (slides actually) more modular. (For example, to have multiple presentations that reuse different sets of slides, without loading unnecessary packages or maintaining `main` files).

Comment: You can try `\input{apackage.sty}` or `\makeatletter\input{apackage.sty}\makeatother` instead of `\usepackage{apackage}`. For some packages it *might* work, but probably for most it won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David Carlisle has already mentioned the standalone package, this is a MWE how to use it:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120060/120953
% "packages that do some of their jobs \AtBeginDocument are likely to fail" with subpreambles (egreg)
% => must be loaded in main document as well
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\input{content/section-01}
\input{content/section-02}
\end{document}
```

content/section-01.tex:

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems,shadings}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Koch curve}{\rule{F -> F-F++F-F}}

\begin{document}
\section{TikZ}
\tikz\shadedraw[shading=color wheel] [l-system={Koch curve, step=2pt, angle=60, axiom=F++F++F, order=4}] lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\end{document}
```

content/section-02.tex:

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section{siunitx}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=7.6] }
\toprule
Prefix & {Value} \\
\midrule
\si{\mega} & 1 000 000 \\
\si{\kilo} & 1 000 \\
\si{\milli} & .001 \\
\si{\micro} & .000 001 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

content/section-01.tex and content/section-02.tex can be compiled on there own as well as be included into main.tex.

Comment: Ah, `subpreambles`, I didn't know about it. This sound more like what I am looking for. Plus, I have standalone per slide preview.

Answer (score 5):

In general no. (If comparing with C remember that TeX is a macro processor, so you should compare with the C pre-processor and any definitions made by two #include files in the same file). Packages can only be included in the preamble.

However for a slide, if it is a self-standing chunk of text with little dependency on text in other slides then you have the possibility of compiling the slides as separate 1-page documents and then including the generated pdf, so

```
\begin{slide}
\includegraphics{slide1.pdf}
\end{slide}
```

the `standalone` package has some facilities for arranging document inclusion using this kind of technique in the background, or you can just do it directly.

Comment: Actually `standalone` is one step closer to what I want. It would be perfect if the package could read ahead the dependencies from the standalone included files.

Comment: @alfC  if using a standalone-like system the included files have no dependencies as they are processed separately, but perhaps I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: You understood perfectly, the feature that @jakun mentioned solves this long standing problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it seems that what you really want to do is to be able to load particular packages only when they are needed by particular include files. As other people have said, you can't do this in the included files because `\usepackage{...}` needs to go into the preamble. You presumably also want this to be fairly "automatic" so that you do not have to keep on checking to see exactly which packages are needed by each of the included files.

What you can do is create your own "style file" that loads all of the required packages for you. I am thinking of a "package" `myfileoptions.sty` that you load with a command like

```
\usepackage[filea,filec]{myfileoptions}
```

and the `myfileoptions` package is smart enough to know which packages to load for the input files `filea.tex` and `fileb.tex`.

Here is a possible mock-up for `myfileoptions.sty` :

```
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\newif\ifTikz\Tikzfalse
\newif\ifTcolorbox\Tcolorboxfalse

\pgfkeys{/myfileoptions/.is family, /myfileoptions,
  filea/.code = {\global\Tikztrue},
  fileb/.code = {\global\Tcolorboxtrue},
  filec/.code = {\global\Tikztrue
                 \global\Tcolorboxtrue}
}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/myfileoptions}% process options

\ifTikz
   \RequirePackage{tikz}
\fi

\ifTcolorbox
   \RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\fi
```

All this does is load the [pgfopts](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts) package to process the options given to the class file. Inside the class file there are a bunch if `\newif` statements for each possible loaded package and `\pgfkeys` is used to turn these switches on whenever a file needs said package. At the end of `myfileoptions.sty` all of the needed packages are loaded using the corresponding `\newif`.

Of course, you will still need to have `\include{filea}` etc at the place(s) where you want to insert `filea`.